# How to check if a string is missing double quotes in a JSON?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x

Let's suppose I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "array": [{
        "case1": aaaa
        "anotherObject": {
            "surname": weird",
            "name": "something
        }
    }]
}
```

In this case, all values from each key are wrong, and so I need to encapsulate those values inside double quotes. So far, I've only been able to create the following RegEx using a positive lookahead: `:(?=\s)[^\"](\w+)[^\"]`, [here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/qzSKzz/3).

The problem is that this RegEx can only find strings that doesn't have any of the double quotes, so the other two possible cases can't be fixed, and as you can see the in the substitution tab of the live demo, this breaks the JSON structure.

Is it possible to create a RegEx that can capture all possible cases (no double quotes at all or just one double quote at the beginning or at the end of the value)?

Comment: It's always better to fix these issues at the source. Something is producing invalid JSON, so it shouldn't be doing it. Trying to post-fix JSON especially using regex is always messy and hast a really wide range of reasons to fail.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. It's just that this is a really specific case which is not going to be a problem in my case :)